# Why do exponents not distribute over addition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I understand that exponents don't distribute over addition and have seen plenty of examples i.e. $$ (x + y)^2\neq x^2 + y^2 $$ but I'm wondering why that is. Multiplication distributes over addition e.g. $3(2+3) = 3(2) + 3(3)$ so if an exponent is just repeated multiplication why shouldn't the same be true for exponents?

i.e. why does $ (x + y)^2\neq x^2 + y^2 $

Comment: You showed an example of multiplication distributing over addition. Did you try any examples to show, or to disprove, exponentiation distributing over addition?

Comment: @LeeMosher I know examples to disprove it, I'm just wondering **why**.

Comment: Asking why something is false beyond a counterexample is rather vacuous.

Comment: At least for positive integers $ \ n \ $ , $ \ (x+y)^n \ $ means $ \ (x+y) \ \cdot \ (x+y) \ \cdot \  (x+y) \ \cdot \ \ldots \ \cdot \ (x+y) \  $ , the product having $ \ n \ $ factors.  Why should that equal _only_ $ \ x^n \ + y^n \ $ ?

Comment: @DanRust I don't think that's true. Presumably you have some method for constructing counterexamples. They don't appear out of nowhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *Multiplication distributes over addition [..], so if [exponentiation] is just repeated multiplication why shouldn't the same be true [..] ?*

Multiplication distributes over addition, and if you repeatedly multiply by the ***same*** quantity or quantities, then that too distributes over addition: for example, $c(a+b) = ca + cb$ (doing multiplication once), $c^2(a+b) = c^2a + c^2b$ (multiplying by $c$ twice), $c^n(a + b) = c^n a + c^n b$ (multiplying $n$ times by by $c$).

But repeatedly multiplying $a$ with itself, repeatedly multiplying $b$ with itself, and finally adding the two *is a different thing* from repeatedly multiplying by $a + b$. There is no reason to expect that repeatedly multiplying by **different** things should somehow distribute over repeatedly multiplying by something else.

The quantity $(a + b)^n$ means that you repeatedly multiply it by $a + b$. The quantity $a^n$ means that you repeatedly multiply by $a$, and $b^n$ means that you repeatedly multiply by $b$. As you're multiplying by *different* things, the results can be arbitrarily different.

In the specific case of $(a + b)^2$ for instance, we can see that it is $(a + b) (a+b)$, and as a multiplication, it does distribute: $(a + b)(a + b) = (a+b)a + (a+b)b$. But $(a)(a) + (b)(b)$ is an entirely unrelated quantity, so it doesn't make sense to expect them to be equal.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this image answers your question:

[image]