# Why is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\neq a+b$, and is there another rule to simplify the square root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. I thought that this was equal to $a^2+b^2$ but it is not. However, even if I convert the square root to powers, I get (based on the power rule $(a^m)^n = a^{mn}$), I get $(a^2+b^2)^{0.5} = a^1 + b^1$ but this is still not true...

Why is this, and is there any other rule for simplifying $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$?

Comment: What do you mean "solving"? Do you need to find an expression that does not involve square roots?

Comment: Are you asking why $(a+b)^2 = (a+b) \cdot (a+b) \neq a^2 + b^2$? If so, just multiply it out and you will see.

Comment: Please do realise that $\sqrt{x+y} \neq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$ and $(a+b)^2 \neq (a^2 +b^2)$. These are the most common high school math errors.

Comment: I see the confusion. I was not sure how to word this :)) Just why isn't $(a^2+b^2)^{0.5} = a^1 + b^1$?

Comment: In general, there is no convenient expression for $\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: The simplest way to see that $\sqrt{a^2 +b^2 }\neq a + b$ is to set $a= b= 1$, which leads to $\sqrt{2} \neq 2$. We know that $\sqrt{2}\approx 1.4142\ldots$

Comment: Perhaps tell us why you need to simplify $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: @npp: As noted above, your issue is equivalent to thinking $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$. This error has come to be known as (the simplest case of) the [freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream), so you are far from alone in making it.

Comment: Things that are true have reasons why they are true. But this is something that is false, and it’s a bit difficult to say why something is false. It just is. Plug in some numbers and you can see that it is often false. It’s like how you can ask why the sky is blue, and there are reasons, but if you ask why the sky isn’t green, you can’t really say much better than “because it is blue, or orange, or red, or purple, or black, depending, but it just happens to never be green.”  This isn’t satisfying. Could it ever be green? Maybe. But why isn’t it right now? Because it isn’t.

Comment: Relevant: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/926/whence-the-everything-is-linear-phenomenon-and-what-can-we-do-about-it, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630339/pedagogy-how-to-cure-students-of-the-law-of-universal-linearity

Comment: More on the "Universal Law of Linearity" at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630339/pedagogy-how-to-cure-students-of-the-law-of-universal-linearity

Comment: Surely this has been asked before?

Comment: @Aaron Not really it is easy to say why this is wrong. It is a misapplication of the distributive property... That is to say that the student is trying to distribute an exponent across addition. When exponents are not distributive across addition. The geometric proof of this is simple and easy to understand. Draw a line of length A+B, square it. Does the area equal A squared + B squared? no? why not. Though my explanation of it is rather bad. Also needed is an explanation that square roots are exponents, though the student seems to understand this.

Comment: @Questor there is a big difference between “why is this false” and “why would someone mistakenly think this is true.”  If someone can address why they believe something false, then we can address the flaw in their reasoning, but that doesn’t answer “why is this false,” it answers “why doesn’t this show that it is true?” And that is simply moving the problem around: instead of asking “why is this thing false” you are asking “why is that thing it depends on false?”  Here, if you push the question to “why doesn’t squaring distribute” you can say what does happen, but that may or may not be enough

Comment: @Aaron if we look at his logic, he is trying to distribute powers across addition. He doesn't understand why he cannot. Therefore an explanation of the distributive rule and how/why things are distributive across parenthesis will explain why what he is doing is wrong.

There are only a couple of things in mathematics that there is not a good explanation as to why it is wrong/right (the three base axioms). One of those is why 1 + 1 = 2 instead of 3 or 4. Everything else has a clear explanation (or not so clear, but an explanation nonetheless) as to why it is wrong or right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that (with some restriction):
$$ (a^m)^n = a^{mn}$$

It is also true that:
$$ [(ab)^{m}]^n = [a^{m}.b^m]^n=[ab]^{mn}$$

You say:

> $(a^2+b^2)^{0.5} = a^1 + b^1$

However **This is not a general rule** when you have "addition" operation raised to a power. In this specific case it is true at least when $a=b=0$

In case you have $(x+y)^m$, where $m$ is an positive integer, there is an expansion for this using the Binomial Theorem.

In case you have $(x+y)^r$, where $r$ is not an integer, there is an infinite series for this case using several approximation methods such as Taylor Expansion. There is also a binomial expansion for Fractional Exponents.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is the simplest form already.

Comment: Ahh yea - "simplify" was probably the word I was looking for an not "solve". Thanks. But can you explain further why this is not true: $(a^2+b^2)^{0.5} = a^1 + b^1$?

Comment: Square both side and you got $a^2+b^2=\left(a+b\right)^2$. But $\left(a+b\right)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2\neq a^2+b^2$

Answer (score 2):

In power rule that you mentioned, namely $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$, $a^m$ is a single number, whereas in $(a^2+b^2)^{0.5}$, the 0.5'th power is applied to a sum, so this is a different case.

To see that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=a+b$ is really false, find a counterexample. Take a=3 and b=4 for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt amounts to

$$\sqrt s=s$$ which is obviously wrong.

Your second attempt does not fit with the power rule.

$$\sqrt{s^2}=s^{1/2\cdot2}=s$$ would be right, but is not what you considered.

---

Now have a look at

$$\sqrt{1+t^2}$$ and try to somehow relate it to $t$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is very tempting to assume that $(a+b)^{2}$ is equal to $a^{2} + b^{2}$, when, in fact, it is not.

Thus $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is not equal to $a+b$. $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ is about as simplified as you can go.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to start with a principle that should be taught in all schools:

**In Mathematics, Nothing Is True** unless there’s a proof that it’s true.

There are a lot of formulas that look very pretty and seem very reasonable, and are true besides, like $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$, but you should have been shown in school *why* that formula is true.

You were undoubtedly hoping that the equally pretty and reasonable formula $(a+b)^n=a^n+b^n$ would be true, but there’s no proof for this. In fact, it’s **false**, but we have something much better, a formula with a stern and crystalline beauty of its own, called the Binomial Theorem:
$$
(a+b)^n=a^n+na^{n-1}b + \frac{n(n-1)}2a^{n-2}b^2+\cdots+\frac{n!}{(n-j)!j!}a^{n-j}b^j+\cdots+nab^{n-1}+b^n\,,
$$
valid when $n$ is a positive whole number.

The moral of my sermon? Don’t ask why an equation or formula isn’t true, because most are not true. Rather, ask what *is* true.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the titular questions, which are very clear:

1. The reason that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\ne a +b$ is that when you square $a+b$ you don't get back $a^2+b^2$ as you should have if indeed that was the square root. In fact, you have instead $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+ b^2,$ which is off by the term $2ab.$
2. Well, there's no other way given all we know that we can simplify $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ further. It's the square root of a sum of two squares, and if $a$ and $b$ are positive it represents the length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle with legs of lengths $a$ and $b.$

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit necro but I am surprised no one mention the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)<sup>1</sup>. The reason this is not working out is because of a a misapplication of the distributive property probably due to the explanation of numaths<sup>1</sup>.

You are trying distribute exponents across addition, but exponentiation is not distributive across addition<sup>2</sup>. As an aside a square root is an exponentiation to a $\frac{1}{2}$ power ($\sqrt{x} = x^\frac{1}{2}$)

You are probably used to distributing multiplicands, which is valid as multiplication is distributive across addition. In other words multiplying the sum of two or more addends produces the same result as multiplying the addends individually, and then summing the products. Using numbers:

$2(1+3) = 2 \times 1 + 2 \times 3 = 8$

$2(1 + 3) = 2(4) = 8$

Proof that exponentiation is not distributive across addition by example.

$(1+2)^2 = (3)^2 = 9 \neq 1^2 +2^2 = 1 + 4 = 5$

A more complete explanation why exponentiation is not distributive across addition can be found [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762503/1101546) or by analysis in my geometric proofs.

#### So how does this apply to my question?

Because exponentiation is not distributive across addition one cannot distribute the exponent across the addends. This $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = (a^2 + b^2) ^\frac{1}{2} = a^{2 \times \frac{1}{2}} + b^{2 \times \frac{1}{2}} = a + b$, is invalid because of an illegal operation (distributing the exponent). Thus it is not possible to simplify $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ more.

---

Geometric proof that multiplication is distributive across addition:

[[image: Rectangle showing that <span class=]$A \times (B \times C) == A \times B + A \times C)$3" />

$A \times (B+C)$ is the same as finding the area of a rectangle with a side of length A and a side of length $B+C$, which from the picture is made up of a rectangle with sides A/B and a rectangle with sides A/C.

Geometric proof that exponentiation is not distributive across addition:

[[image: Square box showing how <span class=]$(A+B) \times (A+B)$ does not equal $A^2 + B^2$" />

Not my best drawing but, $(A+B)^2$ is the same as finding the area of a square with a side of length A+B, from the image we see that square is made up of a Square with length A ($A^2$), square with length B ($B^2$), and two rectangles with an A side and a B side ($A \times B$).

As we can see, if we were to distribute the exponent thru the parenthesis we would miss out on rectangles AB, and BA. if $A = B$ then we have removed half the area of the square created by squaring $A+B$

You can perform this experiment yourself! Get a ruler and draw out the lengths on a sheet of paper.

---

<sup>1</sup> not really surprised as new math which does a horrible job at explaining simple mathematical concepts.

<sup>2</sup> However it is distributive across multiplication:

$(2*3)^2 = (2^2 * 3^2) =4 \times 9 = 36$

$(2*3)^2 = (6) ^ 2 = 36$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Additional supporting information... The distributive property is a basic mathematical property that I learned in 3rd grade? And this answer is more correct then all of the other answers because it is using an actual mathematical property rather then lots of pointless words?

Comment: Yes, but you need to edit your answer to include this information.

Comment: Added geometric proofs.